# Ruby not installed but irb works ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, irb

I seem to have two `irb` (`from package 'ruby' (main)` and `from package 'ruby1.8' (universe)`) and typing irb works, but I can't use any installed packages, and `apt-get remove ruby` says this package is not installed. I followed [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04) to try to install ruby 2.3 because whenever I used `sudo apt-get install ruby` it would install 1.9 instead of 2.3.

Comment: I recommend you to use ruby version manager. Personally I prefer `rbenv`.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried installing `rvm` but ubuntu won't recognise the command after it's installed.

Comment: read the [docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation)

Comment: It's typical to install an older Ruby version with `sudo apt-get install ruby` and then use a version manager to install a newer version alongside it.